# Php pear packages installation and use vs php

Tags: php, pear

i'm an intermediate php developer , I read about Pear Packages and I think that it is good .
Should I use pear or continue develop my level with php oop?
I had a hosting in bluehost , how can i add the package to my page , and also How i can do that with my wamp local Host then transfer to blueHost
??
Thank you

Comment: If you think that PEAR is good wait till you hear about [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: my question is does all php developer turn to libs like pear and so!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want to accomplish.

Pear has a lot of really useful libraries, but it comes down to what you need to get done and whether any pear libraries will help you do that.

You can install pear package on the command line, typically with the following syntax:

pear install

Of course pear needs to be installed for that to work. On Debian-based systems including Ubuntu:

apt-get install php-pear

On RHEL-based systems including CentOS:

yum install php-pear

(both of those assume you are logged in as root. If not then use 'sudo' to execute)

Comment: Oh just re-read your post.. on a WAMP server it's a bit different. http://www.geeksengine.com/article/install-pear-on-windows.html